# Warning: count(): must be an array or object that implements Countable

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have migrated to a new server which is using PHP v7 (from my PHP v5.4) and am now being displayed errors on my website.

This is the lines of code which is returning the error:

```
// The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
$ip = ip2long($ip);
// The $ip would now look something like: 1073732954
if(!count($ip) > 0 || !preg_match('/^\d+$/', $ip) || empty($ip)) {
    $ip="0000000000";
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like it might be new behavior with 7.2, https://github.com/processwire/processwire-issues/issues/408 Checking the type before usage seems to be the solution.

Comment: Those who are facing problem as: `if ( count($articles)){..}` in **CodeIgniter**, they should use: `if ( count((array)$articles)){..}` as [here](https://github.com/processwire/processwire-issues/issues/408#issuecomment-337931543)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ip2long` never returned an array. I think you can safely remove `!count($ip) > 0 ||` from your condition.

Comment: You could also just do `if ($ip === false)` since `ip2long` returns `false` on error, or a long integer on success. No need for regexes.